# I want to save my plotly in svg format, but I get an error and cannot save it

Tags: python, plotly

I want to save my plotly in svg format, but I get an error and cannot save it.
I could have converted it to `html` by using `plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename= 'aaa.html')`, but it didn't work.

```py
fig = px.line(
    df_list[i],
    x=x_axis,
    y=y_axis,
    color="species",
    color_discrete_sequence=colors
)
fig.write_image("SVG/aa.svg")
```

error message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-2f45787db90f> in <module>
     27     )
     28 #     plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename= 'aaa.html')
---> 29     fig.write_image("SVG/aa.svg")
     30 #     plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename= 'aaaa.svg')

c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py in write_image(self, *args, **kwargs)
   3249         import plotly.io as pio
   3250 
-> 3251         return pio.write_image(self, *args, **kwargs)
   3252 
   3253     # Static helpers

c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\plotly\io\_kaleido.py in write_image(fig, file, format, scale, width, height, validate, engine)
    242     # -------------
    243     # Do this first so we don't create a file if image conversion fails
--> 244     img_data = to_image(
    245         fig,
    246         format=format,

c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\plotly\io\_kaleido.py in to_image(fig, format, width, height, scale, validate, engine)
    100         from ._orca import to_image as to_image_orca
    101 
--> 102         return to_image_orca(
    103             fig,
    104             format=format,

c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\plotly\io\_orca.py in to_image(fig, format, width, height, scale, validate)
   1533     # Make sure orca sever is running
   1534     # -------------------------------
-> 1535     ensure_server()
   1536 
   1537     # Handle defaults

c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\plotly\io\_orca.py in ensure_server()
   1388         # Validate orca executable only if server_url is not provided
   1389         if status.state == "unvalidated":
-> 1390             validate_executable()
   1391         # Acquire lock to make sure that we keep the properties of orca_state
   1392         # consistent across threads

c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\plotly\io\_orca.py in validate_executable()
   1074 
   1075     if executable is None:
-> 1076         raise ValueError(
   1077             """
   1078 The orca executable is required to export figures as static images,

ValueError: 
The orca executable is required to export figures as static images,
but it could not be found on the system path.

Searched for executable 'orca' on the following path:
```

Comment: Static image generation requires the installation of a separate module. Please refer to [this page](https://plotly.com/python/static-image-export/).

Comment: So you needed a new installation. Thanks to you, I solved the problem. Thank you very much.